# Magento 1.7 WYSIWYG

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, product, presentation

I have a problem with magento 1.7 (WYSIWYG).
My problem is that I can't have a proper description of the product when I use the WYSIWYG.
For example if I write in the WYSIWYG my product description, on site web site I will have a presentation which isn't the same.
The WYSIWYG puts html tags for each line return.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found in the past that with some themes the description is run through the `nl2br` function first. This will replace all new lines with `<br>` tags. Look in your `view.phtml` template file for this and remove the `nl2br` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to find the real problem.

In the file description.phtml in the `template/easytabs` folder, I removed the `nl2br`.
And then it works fine.

Comment: You're welcome. If it answered your question, please mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have custom css on the front causing it to appair different, view source both the admin (WYSIWYG) and on the website to see if the html are the same. If they are the same then check your custom css

Answer (score 0):

In the file description.phtml in the template/easytabs folder, I removed the `nl2br`.
And then it works fine.